# What is known about optimization of spectral properties of matrices over finite fields?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

[I am solving the characteristic polynomial over complex numbers but since the matrices are symmetric all eigenvalues are real]

- Like for symmetric $d-$regular matrices over 0/1 or 0/1/-1 what are some known optimization results about their possible spectral radius or spectral gap? [..I am calling a symmetric matrix to be $d-$regular if it has $d$ non-zero entries in each row and column..]
- We do not know of a method to exactly calculate the roots of a polynomial and hence we can't calculate the eigenvalues of a matrix exactly. Given then I suppose determining the spectral gap of a graph is also not possible to do exactly. Is that right?

Comment: If you're looking for real eigenvalues, what does the "over finite fields" in the title mean?

Comment: If by "exactly" you mean as expressions in rational numbers and radicals, then that is correct, in general the spectral gap of a graph can not be expressed in that way.

Comment: Just wanted to emphasize that the entries are restricted to come from some specific integers.

Comment: By the way, there are very good ways to get numerical approximations to the eigenvalues of a matrix.  These generally do **not** involve working with the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: What else would be the way to express the spectral gap of a given matrix?

Comment: no matter how good an approximation one gets its never going to be sufficient to answer various possible questions about spectral gaps - like say deciding if a graph is ramanujan or not.

Comment: Well, you could use something like Maple's "RootOf" notation.  In principle it is possible to decide questions such as " is $\lambda \le 2 \sqrt{d-1}$" by using Sturm's theorem to count roots of polynomials in intervals.

Comment: Can you kindly link to any reference about how this is possible?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem 
http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=sturm

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of determining whether a graph is Ramanujan using Maple.
I'll take a random $5$-regular connected graph with $20$ vertices.

```
with(GraphTheory):
G:= RandomGraphs:-RandomRegularGraph(20,5,connected);
A:= AdjacencyMatrix(G);
P:= factor(LinearAlgebra:-CharacteristicPolynomial(A,t));
```

$$ \left( t-5 \right)  \left( {t}^{19}+5\,{t}^{18}-25\,{t}^{17}-153\,{t}
^{16}+172\,{t}^{15}+1730\,{t}^{14}+158\,{t}^{13}-9144\,{t}^{12}-5832\,
{t}^{11}+23788\,{t}^{10}+22275\,{t}^{9}-28621\,{t}^{8}-33055\,{t}^{7}+
12253\,{t}^{6}+19109\,{t}^{5}+315\,{t}^{4}-3321\,{t}^{3}-557\,{t}^{2}+
79\,t+15 \right) 
$$

```
P2:= op(2,P);
sturm(sturmseq(P2,t),t,4,5);
```

$$ 0 $$

No eigenvalues in this interval, so yes, it is Ramanujan.

[image]

Comment: And how do you know that this is error free? Since we cannot find the roots of a polynomial exactly in anyway how is this exact?

Comment: Sturm's theorem is a theorem.  It is exact!  With its help, we can count roots in an interval without actually finding them.  For a very simple case, we can easily tell that the polynomial $x^7 + x - 1$ has exactly one positive root, without having to compute it.

Comment: Thanks! This is a very method to me. I always thought of finding roots through exact solution or as approximation methods. Sturm sequence is a totally new way to do it!